# In excel how to match the given input between min and max age colums

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have an Excel file were I have 3 columns. I will explain the steps:

**Step 1**: I will be giving an input age (eg: 25).

**Step 2**: Then we need to match the minimum and maximum column .

**Step 3**: Once matched the value it should return from age group (eg 25-35). Multiple age groups can also be returned.

I need help with this Excel formula.

I have tried index match but no success.

Comment: Use the Match on the Minimum column and return which ever column you want.

Comment: Why *"Multiple age groups can also be returned"*? The groups don't overlap. Can the given age be lower than 5 or greater than 60? Like Scott said, you can just use only one of the columns to find the right group.

Comment: Change the ages so 5-24 is just 5, 25-35 is just 215. The vlookup() or match() will work correctly as long as you set the range argument.

Comment: @ashish521, I see you accepted my answer, but I still wonder about my question above regarding the "multiple age groups".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be an easier way, but this is an option:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(MINIFS($C$2:$C$8,$C$2:$C$8,">="&F33),$C$2:$C$8))
```

*(where `F33` is the cell with the age)*

Explanation:

```
=MINIFS($C$2:$C$8,$C$2:$C$8,">="&F33)
```

This returns the minimum value which is greater than the given age in the table. I tried to use this function to directly return the range name, but it doesn't work; it only returns a number. So from the second range, it picks all the values which satisfy the condition, and then returns the corresponding (same row) value from the first range. E.g.: if age=52, from the second range it will pick 55 and 60 (just as filters), and then take the minimum value from the last two rows of the first range (55).

```
=MATCH(MINIFS(...),$C$2:$C$8)
```

Looks for the `MINIFS` result value (55) in the range and returns the row index; 6 in this case. First row is 1, and remember it's relative to the range, not the whole sheet.

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(...))
```

Just picks rows 6 from the given range.